# Drupal Commerce Add input widget

Tags: drupal, drupal-commerce

Left with no other option but to ask

With Drupal Commerce, I created

1. a product type
2. added a product as a entity
3. created a node with a relationship towards the entity.

Working fine.
I want to add a custom text input for a product type. for example a branding name on a product

From what I gathered you would either use a custom line item or add a widget(no idea how though)

Are there any guides available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the product content type you created and click on manage fields. This page lists out all the fields that are declared for the content type. This page also lets you add new fields to the content type. Add a new field of type text and that should be done.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Ive tried your solution but, i believe this method would be used to display text in this field. I want a user to be able to input text.

Comment: http://drupal.org/project/editablefields may be this is what you are looking for. If the user has sufficient permissions he would be able to edit the field.

Comment: Ended up using https://drupal.org/project/commerce_custom_product. Also installed commerce kickstart to see how to set it up.